# What is the HTTP/1 equivalent of the HTTP/2 `:scheme` header?

Tags: http2

I'm writing a proxy from HTTP/2 to HTTP/1 and vice-versa.

When I have an incoming HTTP/2 request, which defines `:scheme`, what header should I map that to for my proxied HTTP/1 request?

The closest thing I can find is https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7239#section-5.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mapping the HTTP/2 `:scheme` pseudo header to HTTP/1.1 `X-Forwarded-Proto` header would be correct.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use `X-Forwarded-Proto` as an HTTP/2 header - what's the point of `:scheme`? Is it to standardise `X-Forwarded-Proto`? To me, `:scheme` seems like something new, semantically speaking. To put it another way - is there a valid use case where you'd have both `:scheme` **and** `X-Forwarded-Proto`?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30900008/purpose-of-pseudo-colon-header-fields. Pseudo-headers are part of HTTP/2 and apply to the current request. If the current request has been forwarded by a HTTP/2-to-HTTP/2 proxy, then it may well be that both `:scheme` and `Forwarded: proto=...` are present (`X-Forwarded-Proto` is now obsolete) and they may have different values: the HTTP/2-to-HTTP/2 proxy received a `https` request, but forwarded it as clear text, so `:scheme` would be `http`.

Comment: @ioquatix you have yourself linked it in your question, its [RFC 7239](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7239).

Comment: hehe, yeah I found it eventually :p

Answer (score 2):

You basically shouldn't map it.

For a start HTTP has no direct equivalent to the `:scheme` pseudo-header. The request was a relative path (e.g. `/path/page/`) rather than an absolute path (e.g. `https://www.example.com/path/page/`) and the Host header contained just the server name and not the scheme.

So the connection knows whether it is HTTP or HTTPS and this is exposed to webservers and the like (e.g. in the `REQUEST_SCHEME` variable for Apache) but at an HTTP level it doesn't know.

If acting as an intercepting proxy and taking one HTTP/2 connection, and forwarding requests to another, then you should open a HTTP or HTTPS connection for that second connection, as you see fit depending what the downstream system supports.

As sbordet points out if you want to make the downstream system aware of what the original scheme was then you can use `X-Forwarded-Proto` header (technically obseleted but still used) or the `Forwarded` header, but that's more for informational purposes rather than a direct mapping of what was in the original request. The scheme is related to the *current* request.

Answer (score 0):

According to [RFC 7540, section 8.1.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#section-8.1.2):

> While HTTP/1.x used the message start-line (see [RFC7230],
> Section 3.1) to convey the target URI, the method of the request, and
> the status code for the response, HTTP/2 uses special pseudo-header
> fields beginning with ':' character (ASCII 0x3a) for this purpose.

And:

> The ":scheme" pseudo-header field includes the scheme portion of
> the target URI ([RFC3986], Section 3.1).

> ":scheme" is not restricted to "http" and "https" schemed URIs.  A
> proxy or gateway can translate requests for non-HTTP schemes,
> enabling the use of HTTP to interact with non-HTTP services.

So, if you're proxing HTTP, it should be "http" and if you're proxying HTTPS, it should be "https".

---

Reading again, I can see that I may have had the sense of the question the wrong way around (I was thinking HTTP1 client, HTTP2 server). But the above two quotes are still the relevant ones. You don't put `:scheme` in an HTTP1 header - it forms part of the URI that you place in the message start line.

Comment: It seems to me like the effective scheme is computed according to [this logic](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-5.5) for HTTP/1 and is explicitly specified in HTTP/2. Would you agree with that?