# Unable to use "request" library with headers

Tags: node.js, request, http-headers, google-chrome-devtools, request-headers

Using Chrome dev tools I can see all the requests made. I want to replicate one of them using a script. The request is replicable as replaying it from dev tools works. I'm using this code:

```js
let request = require("request");
request.put("<hidden>", {
    "headers": {
        ":authority": "<hidden>",
        ":method": "PUT",
        ":path": "/api/<hidden>",
        ":scheme": "https",
        "accept": "*/*",
        "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
        "accept-language": "en-US",
        "authorization": "<hidden>",
        "content-length": "0",
        // and more
    }
}, (err, response, body) => {
    console.log(err);
    console.log(response.statusCode);
    console.log(body);
});
```

The console says:

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_HTTP_TOKEN]: Header name must be a valid HTTP token [":authority"]
    at ClientRequest.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:487:3)
    at new ClientRequest (_http_client.js:221:14)
    at Object.request (https.js:309:10)
    at Object.request (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\puppeteer-core\node_modules\agent-base\patch-core.js:25:22)
    at Request.start (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\request\request.js:751:32)
    at Request.end (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\request\request.js:1505:10)
    at end (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\request\request.js:564:14)
    at Immediate._onImmediate (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\request\request.js:578:7)
    at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:439:21) {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_HTTP_TOKEN'
}
```

I tried not using `.put()`, or specifying `method` and `body` properties. Same results.

Comment: That library is [deprecated](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142). But why *do* you have headers with a `:` prefix?

Comment: This is how they appear in devtools. Also without `:` the request seems to fail

Comment: But those "headers" just seem to repeat the request's URI and method anyway. Realistically with all the `<hidden>` there's not much we can do, without a [mre] to replicate.

Comment: `// and more`. It doesn't work without them, so I wanted to try with them

Comment: And *what* more? By that point you're out of the invalid colon-prefixed headers anyway, so it's unclear whether they'd be relevant.

Comment: Read e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/30900008/3001761 - as I said above, the first four just repeat information that you provide by other means, so remove the `:`-prefixed psuedo-headers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Headers that show with a leading colon are "pseudo-headers".  You don't actually send them yourself with the `request()` library as they are an illegal http 1.1 header format.

You can read about them here: [Purpose of pseudo colon-header fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30900008/purpose-of-pseudo-colon-header-fields).

You should be able to remove all the pseudo-headers and just make sure that the information in them is properly specified elsewhere in your request (url, method, etc...) which they would normally already be.